# SQLite Database Created table with 2 columns but error shows only one column in table

Tags: android, sqlite

Following is the structure of the table I am trying to create:

```
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "WidgetDatabase.db";
    private static final String TABLE_WIDGET = "widgets";

    private static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "widgetid";

    public WidgetPrefs(Context context) {
        super(context , DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_WIDGET + " (" +
                KEY_CITY + " TEXT," +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER," +
                "PRIMARY KEY(" + KEY_ID  + ")" +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUESTION_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_WIDGET);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Now when I try to run a function like this:

```
public String getCity(int widgetId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_CITY + " FROM " + TABLE_WIDGET + ";", null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if (widgetId == cursor.getInt(1)) {
                        Log.i("City", cursor.getString(0));
                        return cursor.getString(0);
                    }
                }
                while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
```

I get error in the logcat saying `Failed to read row 0, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 1 columns.`

I am able to add to this table (I can confirm that, please check the below picture)

```
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.`
```

[image: Table Contents 2 columns present]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cursor has, as the message says, 1 row with 1 column. Column offsets start at 0. So specifying column 1 as an offset will fail.

That is `widgetId == cursor.getInt(1)` will not work as there is no column 1, just column 0 due to the query only including the 1 column **city**.

Perhaps change the query to include the **widgetID** column as per :-

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WIDGET + ";", null);
```

In which case all columns from the table will be included in the cursor.

The code you have can be simplified to :-

```
    String rv;
    if (while cursor.moveToNext) {
        if (widgetId == cursor.getInt(1)) {
            rv = cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
            return rv;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return null;
```

The reasoning :-

- A Cursor will never be null when returned from an SQLite method that generates a cursor, so checking for null is useless. A Cursor will exist although it may be empty.
- All the Cursor move???? methods will return false if the move cannot be made. So `while(cursor.moveToNext)` will return false if the cursor cannot move to the next and the while loop will not be entered. This copes with an empty cursor so the check using `moveToFirst` is not required.
- You should always clode a cursor when done with it. `return cursor.getString(0);` will not close the cursor. Hence the introduction of the variable rv to hold the value extracted from the cursor, thus allowing the cursor to be closed before returning.

---

An alternative approach would be to use a **WHERE** clause in the query to select the respective row.

This could be

```
    "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WIDGET + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + "=" + Integer.toString(widgetId);
```

It is also better to use the SQLite convenience methods when they can be applied, so rather than using the `rawQuery` is is considered, by many, that the `query` method is better practice. This builds the SQL and executes it.

As such your `getCity` method could be :-

```
public String getCity(long widgetId) {
    String rv;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
                        TABLE_WIDGET, //Table to extract cursor from
                        null, // Columns, null = all columns
                        KEY_ID + "=?", // Where clause, ? indicates an arg
                        new String[]{Long.toString(widgetId)}, //args
                        null,
                        null,
                        null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CITY));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return rv;
}
```

**Notes**

- Ideally you should use `long` not `int` for  an **id** column. This is because the rowid (for which your id column is an alias) can reach a value as high as 9223372036854775807. [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html) .
- There is no need to loop through the returned cursor, as you know that it will return either an empty cursor or a cursor with 1 row.
- The `query` method is explained in more detail here [query](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). There are 4 methods that have different signatures.
- args (4th parameter), a String array, will replace the ?'s in the where clause (3rd parameter). The number of elements in the array should match the number of ?'s. They are used in sequence i.e. the first ? will be replaced by the value obtained from the first element, the second ? by the value from the second element etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is... you are selecting just one column... KEY_CITY

SELECT " + KEY_CITY + " FROM " + TABLE_WIDGET + ";"

So, the result for your query has just one column

Answer (score 1):

i ran your code, the problem was with

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_CITY + " FROM " + TABLE_WIDGET + ";", null);
```

your table has two columns and you're selecting only KEY_CITY column. update it with following code

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_WIDGET + ";", null);
```